# Error connecting to Google Adwords through APIlity after killing script. Why?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have to use the Google APIlity client (through v13) to access account information. If I am running the script I wrote and I kill it on the command line using CTRL+C, I get an error when I try to access the API using:

```
$apilityUser->getManagersClientAccounts()
```

Any Ideas?

```
require_once('apility/apility.php');
$apilityUser = new APIlityUser(
 $email,
 $password,
 $client_email,
 $developer_token,
 $application_token
);

# get all of the accounts (IT DIES HERE)
if(!$emailAccounts = $apilityUser->getManagersClientAccounts()){
 fwrite($STDERR, '** ERROR ** There was an error while trying to connect to the partner!'."\n");
 fclose($STDERR);
 exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when the script is stopped, if it is caching the WSDL, it leaves the cached WSDL in the cache folder. When I remove the cached WSDL, it allows me to connect again. I finally discovered the resolution and figured I would post it here in case someone else runs into the same problem.